# Youtube API private locks my Shorts videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have set up my YouTube API and I can post regular videos without them getting private. But when I put #Shorts in the title it gets locked as private. It is not copyright claimed. I know that this is propably because of the youtube API not allowing my video to post. My question is what do I have to do so that I can upload Shorts using the yt API.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [video.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) you will find the cause of your issue

[image]

your app needs to be verified before you can upload videos and have them set to public.  This issue is unrelated to the fact that its shorts.